# How can we hide files in SD card programmatically in android without using dot(.)?

Tags: android

How can we hide files in SD card in android without using dot and make visible in application.

Answer (score 1):

Encrypt file name without any file extension(like .jpeg or .png) so user & file manager also cannot understand it.